# Заполнение нового списка из файла

Tags: c

Нужно из файла (блокнота) заполнить односвязный список

моя структура:

```
struct prog {
char name[80];
unsigned int kol;
double time1;
double time2;

struct prog* next;
};
```

вот как я попытался сделать но ничего не вышло:

```
void zad8(prog* head) {

FILE* g;
prog* p = head;
fopen_s(&g, "fileG.txt", "r");
while (!feof(g)) {
    fscanf(g, "%-18s", p->name);
    fscanf(g, "%-22u",  &p->kol);
    fscanf(g, "%-32.2lf",  &p->time1);
    fscanf(g, "%-28.2lf", &p->time2);
    fscanf(g, "\n");
    p = p->next;
}
fclose(g);
}
```

вот как выглядит содержимое блокнота:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fPMq.png]

Comment: По крайней мере анализ EOF надо делать **после** чтения. Поэтому лучше читать всю строку одним `fscanf` (кстати [fscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf) возвращает **количество** успешно прочитанных элементов формата) и читать `\n` им не надо. Если требуется уверенность (проверка формата исходного файла), что запись целиком находится в одной строке, то читайте по строкам (например, [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)), а потом sscanf-ом из строки

Comment: А если файл не из блокнота?